# Substitute values in an array with a random number if value>1

Tags: arrays, matlab, random

I have an array (1000 x 8) of values generated from a log-normal distribution representing the % die-off of bacteria on a surface after an hour. The problem is that some values are larger than 100% so I'd like to replace them with a random value between 0 and 1.

```
dieOff=zeros(1000,8); %make empty 1000X8 array
m = 0.9; % 90% die-off
v = 0.01;% std from experiment


mu = log((m^2)/sqrt(v+m^2)); %conver to lognorm
sigma = sqrt(log(v/(m^2)+1));

dieOff=lognrnd(mu,sigma,n,k);% generate values

dieOff(dieOff>1)=rand(); %replace with random
```

But it looks like `rand()` only produces 1 value and replaces all the values that are > 1 with that same value which is not what I'd like. How can I fix this in a neat format?

```
histogram(dieOff)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rand()` gives a single number, i.e. you replace *all* values with that same, random, constant. Instead, use a random number for each occurrence:

```
dieOff(dieOff>1)=rand(nnz(dieOff>1),1);
```

`rand(n,k)` gives you an *n*-by-*k* matrix of random numbers between 0 and 1. `rand(n)` gives you an *n*-by-*n* matrix of random numbers (i.e. square), so for `n=1` it is a single number. `rand()` is short for `rand(1)`.